# Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost in my IIS configuration

Tags: iis-7

I receive the message for the past two days.......when **http://localhost** in my **WIN 7**,and **127.0.0.1** also shows the same....
**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** was also in correct format.....

*before two days It was working well...IIS 7,But now not working.....*

but I receive the message....

**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost**

Comment: What about the other browser (safari/IE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the port of IIS has been changed. If not, check your firewall, it may be blocking connection to and from the server.

if u connection using http:// localhost, make sure IIS is running on port 80.

Comment: Thanks  for ur comment...
The best solution that I found was to restart the IIS service from control panel..

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just restarted the laptop and then the problem solved itself.